# Split-Path + Join-Path functionality

Tags: powershell, split

I have a problem concerning the `Split-Path` and `Join-Path` cmdlets of MS PowerShell. I want to copy an entire directory from the folder (including all folder and files therein) `C:\Testfolder` to the folder `C:\TestfolderToReceive`.

For this task I use the following coding:

```
$sourcelist = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | % {
    $childpath = split-path "$_*" -leaf -resolve
    $totalpath = join-path -path C:\TestfolderToReceive -childpath $childpath
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $totalpath
}
```

The problem arises with files which aren't directly in `C:\Testfolder`, but in subfolders of it (EXAMPLE: `C:\Testfolder\TestSubfolder1\Testsub1txt1.txt`). All these files which are not directly in `C:\Testfolder` return "null" via the `$childpath` variable.

For example for the file `C:\Testfolder\TestSubfolder1\Testsub1txt1.txt` I would like it to return `TestSubfolder1\Testsub1txt1.txt` so that a new path called `C:\TestfolderToReceive` will be created by the `Join-Path` functionality.

Could someone explain me what I am doing wrong and explain me the correct way for tackling such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this. [`Copy-Item`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156818.aspx) can do this for you on its own:

```
Copy-Item C:\Testfolder\* C:\TestfolderToReceive\ -Recurse
```

The `\*` part is crucial here, otherwise `Copy-Item` will recreate `TestFolder` inside `C:\TestfolderToReceive`

In this scenario, you could use `Join-Path` to position the `*` correctly:

```
$SourceDir      = 'C:\Testfolder'
$DestinationDir = 'C:\TestfolderToReceive'

$SourceItems = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath '*'
Copy-Item -Path $SourceItems -Destination $DestinationDir -Recurse
```

If you want a list of files copied, you can use the `-PassThru` parameter with `Copy-Item`:

```
$NewFiles = Copy-Item -Path $SourceItems -Destination $DestinationDir -Recurse -PassThru
```